# Cannot use react hook in a locally imported npm dependency while bundling with webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm using a locally linked `npm` package and using `webpack` as a bundler. A component from the imported package throws the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

react.development.js:1621 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1621:21)
    at Button (Button.tsx:25:61)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20069:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21582:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27446:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26555:12)
```

My imported component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./button.css";

type ButtonProps = {
  unpressedContent: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
  pressedContent?: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
  className?: string;
  onClick: Function;
};

export default function Button({
  unpressedContent,
  pressedContent,
  className,
  onClick,
}: ButtonProps) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setPressed(!pressed);
    onClick();
  }

  function getContent() {
    return pressed && pressedContent ? pressedContent : unpressedContent;
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={className}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {getContent()}
    </button>
  );
}
```

The bundled component line that throws the exception:

```
var _b = (0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState)(false), pressed = _b[0], setPressed = _b[1];
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  [
                    "postcss-preset-env",
                    {
                      // Options
                    },
                  ],
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      title: "react-js-front-end-template",
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
  ],
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "book-profile-page-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.36",
    "book-atlas-widgets": "file:../widgets",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack serve --open",
    "build": "npx webpack build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

- As seen, the hook called in a function component, it's a function
  component even after bundling.
- The component works by itself, the error thrown only when it is
  imported to an other project.
- There is no problem with components that are not using react hooks.

Comment: Where do you use the `<Button />`

Comment: In a function component in the main npm project.

Comment: Does it work when you declare your <Button /> component in the same main project and import it from there ?

Comment: Try this, `{ resolve: { extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"], alias: {react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')} } }` in your webpack config